# I need help understanding reinforcement learning code

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I've been trying to solve the OpenAI `MountainCarContinuous-v0` environment for a while but I have been stuck.

After spending weeks on my own trying to solve it, I am now just trying to understand someone else's code. [Here is the link the person used to solve the enviroment](https://github.com/sezan92/Actor-Critic/blob/master/ac_mountain_car.py). Specifically, I need help with the loss function.

In the GitHub code is written as

```
self.norm_dist = tf.contrib.distributions.Normal(self.mu, self.sigma)
self.loss = -tf.log(self.norm_dist.prob(self.action_train) + 1e-5) * self.advantage_train - self.lamb * self.norm_dist.entropy()
```

What is this loss function doing? If you could describe it in simple terms that would help me so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first step, a `normal-ditribution` is defined with `mean` and `variance`. In the next step loss function is defined something like `-A*log(p(a)) + \lambda * entropy`, where A is advantage, p(a) is probability of action which is sampled from the normal-dist and finally entropy of distribution is being added in loss function.